# Ionic2. ion-option is not checked Visually

Tags: data-binding, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have this `ion-option` inside a `ion-list`:

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="year">
    <ion-option checked="true">
      {{year}}
    </ion-option>
    <ion-option *ngFor="#year of years">
      {{year}}
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

And inside the Page/Component I set:

```
this.year  = '2016';
this.day = 30;
this.month = 'Jan';
```

Visually it's not checked, technically, it is.:

[image]

These are the options:

[image]

As it seems it must be a number not string...
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="yearModel">
      <ion-option *ngFor="#year of years" value="{{year}}">
      {{year}}
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

This will show the list of years in your `years` array, and will check the one you have in `yearModel` (I used a different variable name for clarity).

For example if you do `this.yearModel="2016"` in you page file, it will check the year 2016.